# How to get rid of the asynchoronous code here

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have been trying to retrieve the data using the MongoJS driver for node.js.The Code which I am using is as follows

```
     req.on('end', function(){
             var decodedBody = querystring.parse(fullBody);
             story=decodedBody.name;
             var z=new Array();
             console.log(story);
         res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
         res.write('<html><body>');
             db.frames.find({str_id:story}).toArray(function(err,doc){
             console.log(doc);
             for(var t=0;t<doc.length;t++)
                 {
                     var picid=doc[t].pic_id;
                     console.log(picid);               
                     db.pictures.find({_id:picid}).toArray(function(err,pic){
                      res.write('<img src="'+pic[0].name+'"/>');
             });
           } 
        }) 
        res.end('</body></html>'); 
   });
```

The problem here is that because of the asynchronous nature of the code the response gets ends first and then the code inside the block of database gets executed and because of that nothing gets displayed on the browser i.e an image in this case .Thankx in advance.

Comment: have you tried moving the res.end call in the callback of db.frames.find?

Comment: Yeah max I tried all the combinations here.But it didnt work out.Nyways the answer provided below worked and thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't fight the asynchronous nature of node.js, embrace it!

So you should fire off all your requests, marking each one as completed when the response arrives. When all requests are completed, render your images and body/html closing tags.

I don't usually work with node.js, so I can make some mistakes, but it may look like this:

```
res.write('<html><body>');
db.frames.find({str_id:story}).toArray(function(err,doc){
  console.log(doc);

  var completed = {};

  for(var t = 0; t < doc.length; t++) {
    var picid = doc[t].pic_id;
    completed.picid = false;
    console.log(picid);               
    db.pictures.find({_id: picid}).toArray(function(err, pic) {
      // mark request as completed
      completed.picid = pic;


      // check if all requests completed
      var all_finished = true;
      for(var k in completed) {
        if(completed[k] === false) {
          all_finished = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      // render final markup
      if(all_finished) {
        for(var k in completed) {
          var pic = completed[k];
          res.write('<img src="'+pic[0].name+'"/>');
        }
        res.end('</body></html>);
      }
    });


  } 
})
```

Comment: Well, without your data and server it's hard to tell. Time for little debugging, I say.

Comment: Yeah thankx for the help.I have some research on your logic now.Should really praise your brainwork.

Answer (score 1):

just put the `res.end('</body></html>');` inside your `db.frames.find` function. Check when you reached `doc.length - 1` and then send the `end` command.

Comment: I understand that requests in node.js are fully async. If so, then checking for doc.length is unreliable, because some responses might still be on their way.